# How do I find the size of a legend in a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

The answer to
[How to include the outside legend into the generated file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73327720/850781)
is predicated on figuring out the size of a [legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) in inches.

How do I do that? `legend` inherits from [artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html) and neither mentions size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the legend is determined at draw time. To get the height, you have to first draw the figure with `fig.canvas.draw()` and then use `legend.get_window_extent()`. Specifically get height and width with `.height` and `.width`. The values are in pixels and the default DPI of Matplotlib is 100. So take the given values, divide by DPI (100), and that is your value in inches.

See:
[Read height of legend in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258363/read-height-of-legend-in-python)

[Getting the width of a legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988884/getting-the-width-of-a-legend-in-matplotlib)

Using your code from your previous question and just some random plot to show the difference:

```
nrows = 4
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2*nrows))
axes = fig.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=1)
names = [f"name-{n}" for n in range(10)]
for ax in axes:
    for n in names:
        ax.plot(np.arange(10),np.random.normal(size=10),label=n)
legend  = axes[0].legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0,1,1))
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.80)
fig.savefig("test.png")

fig.canvas.draw()
print(f'Height: {legend.get_window_extent().height/100} in')
print(f'Width: {legend.get_window_extent().width/100} in')
```

Output:

```
Height: 1.53 in
Width: 0.7425 in
```

[image]

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.subplots()
axes.plot(x,y, label="test")
legend = plt.legend()
fig.canvas.draw()
print(f'Height: {legend.get_window_extent().height/100} in')
print(f'Width: {legend.get_window_extent().width/100} in')
```

Output:

```
Height: 0.18 in
Width: 0.55125 in
```

[image]